# PHP XML DomDocument - Pulling attributes and child attributes

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, children

```
<tle-type name="Channel" tag="47" mt="true">
  <tle-field name="ChannelId" tag="1" type="String" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
    Description 1.
  </tle-field>           
  <tle-field name="resultCode" tag="2" enum="true" type="ChannelResult" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">     
    Description 2.
  </tle-field>
  <tle-field name="jid" tag="3" type="String" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1">
    Description 3.
  </tle-field>
  <tle-field name="thing" tag="4" type="String" minOccurs="0"  maxOccurs="1">
    Description 5.
  </tle-field>
</tle-type>
```

Above is a section of XML that I am dealing with.  The 'tag' attribute under 'tle-type' is the unique identifier and then in it's children 'tle-field' will be another 'tag' attribute.  I'm essentially looking for a way to identify the first 'tag' 'tle-type', then create a $attribute = "value" out of 'tle-field', with the description in $desc.

While I can pull out the 'tle-type' attribute with tag="x", I cannot seem to pull the child attributes out where the tag = 'y'.  I can just print all the attributes.

```
foreach ($xml->getElementsByTagName('tle-type') as $tag) {
        if($tag->getAttribute('tag') === '47') {
                foreach ($tag->childNodes as $child ) { 
                        foreach ($child->attributes as $t ) {                                                                                        
                                echo "<BR>".$t->nodeName." = ".$t->nodeValue;

                        }   
                }   
        }   
}
```

With the above, I end up with Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in file.php on line 4:

```
foreach ($child->attributes as $t)
```

Yet the attribute names and values show up, minus the description, of course.  I hope I've explained this alright...

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure what the output should be. Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The childnodes, are not only elements, but text nodes, too. So you get the whitespace text nodes. They have no attributes and an error is thrown.

I modified your source to show the classes: https://eval.in/112204

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('tle-type') as $tag) {
  if($tag->getAttribute('tag') === '47') {
    foreach ($tag->childNodes as $child) { 
      var_dump(get_class($child));
    }   
  }   
}
```

So you would have to check if the child is an instance of `DOMElement`. But here is an easier way. Create an Xpath object and use expressions:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);

$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//tle-type[@tag = "47"]/tle-field') as $field) {
  $result[$field->getAttribute('name')] = $field->nodeValue;   
}

var_dump($result);
```

Output: https://eval.in/112222

```
array(4) {
  ["ChannelId"]=>
  string(22) "
    Description 1.
  "
  ["resultCode"]=>
  string(27) "     
    Description 2.
  "
  ["jid"]=>
  string(22) "
    Description 3.
  "
  ["thing"]=>
  string(22) "
    Description 5.
  "
}
```

Comment: Also, OP can just put: $xml->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE; before load(), and his script will work fine, too. :)

Comment: Yes, until someone decides to add a comment to the file :-)

Comment: This worked a treat.  Thank you.  Now I have some more reading to do on xpath. :)  The learning continues.